# VS2012 doesn't run: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore' v4.0.0.0 or one of its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've a problem when I start Visual Studio 2012. It show s an error saying:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Could not load file or assembly '`PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>
> OK

I've re-installed it, but the error remains.

Comment: Very unhealthy.  The Windows Application log should have a more detailed message about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by Turning off the Microsoft .NET framework 4.5. I restarted the PC, re-activated it; and made system update.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this simply by running START -> ALL PROGRAMS -> WINDOWS UPDATE.

It took about 10 minutes to run windows update.

Afterwards, I rebooted my computer and VS 2012 was up and running.

I am running Windows 7 Professional Service pack 1.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.